# Service on amazon to download temporary files

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have to decide one thing, and would be very glad if some one could help me with that.
So the thing is we have an infrastructure on Amazon. Back-end processes write multiple files to the S3. Than when customer request a report, - we launch EMR job and create a result. So, the question is how to give this report file back to the customer?

What I would like to have is some temporary storage, that will give a unique url, that customer can download it from.

I was also thinking about storing result file on S3, but don't know if it's a good idea.

Is there some kind of a service on amazon that can help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a signed URL (that you can later shorten if needed) to download the results file from S3: http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much, I was looking for this for the last couple hours )